# How to parse file data in hapi.js?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, hapi.js

I am trying to parse Excel file data in server using `hapi.js`. I am getting file but data is in binary stream.

This is the code I am using and it need to parse file data to JSON from binary stream. So, XLSX file is coming to server side API as a binary stream. Now I need to read that binary stream and create file back and save locally at server API

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: `${path..'/xlsx/')}get`,
    config: {

        handler: function (request, reply) {
           const payload = request.payload

        console.log(payload);

        reply ('done');
        },
        payload: {
            output: 'stream',
            parse: true,
            allow: 'multipart/form-data'
        },

 if (data.file) {
                var name = data.file.filename;
                var path = dirname + "/uploads/" + name;
                 var file = fs.createWriteStream(path);
                 console.log(path);

                 file.on('error', function (err) { 
                     console.error(err) 
                 });

                 data.file.pipe(file);

                 data.file.on('end', function (err) { 
                     var ret = {
                         filename: data.file.filename,
                         headers: data.file.headers
                    }
                    reply(JSON.stringify(ret));
});
next();
```

Comment: I'd recommend a library like [xlsx](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx) or [exceljs](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs) to handle parsing the excel file. Both of these can read in a stream and go from there.

Comment: Actually xlsx has a [utility function `sheet_to_json`](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx#utilities) which might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Chris.I have used xlsx and excel.js and it works great. Actually earlier i tried with sheetJs but didn't worked.

Comment: I am getting array of numbers by default in server. Any idea ??

Like this ..

ng":false,"ended":true,"endEmitted":true,"reading":false,"sync":false,"neeresumeScheduled":false,"defaultEncoding":"utf8","ranOut":false,"awaitDrain":0,"readingMore":false,"decoder":null,"encoding":null},"readable":false,"domain":{"domain":null,"_[]},"_events":{"end":[null]},"_eventsCount":1,"_data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[80,75,3,4,20,0,6,0,8,0,0,0,33,0,59,72,142,64,105,1,0,0,196,4,0,0,19,0,8,2,91,67,111,110,116,101,110,116,95,84,121,112,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}]